# Stacking kernel density graphs vertically

Tags: r, ggplot2, bayesian

I have a matrix (C) of outputs from a bayesian model with 3000 rows which contain the week number (1-13) in which a given bird breeding behavior (columns; singing, incubating, fledglings etc.) is most likely to occur. I have visualized kernel density estimates for the week in which a behavior is most likely to occur using this code:

```
G <- mcmc_dens(C, pars = c("Singing", "Building", "Incubating", "Nestlings", "Empty Nest", "Fledglings Observed", "Fledgling/Adult Interactions", "Fledgling Foraging"))
G <- G + theme(axis.title = element_text(face="plain",size=12)) + labs(x ="Week") + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:13)
```

...which produces these figures:

[image: Kernel density estimates - figure G]

I would like to stack the figures above one another so that I have one figure with the same x-axis where you can easily see which behaviors peak at the same time, but I don't know how to do this with `mcmc_dens` (i.e. I want the graph for singing to be above building, both singing and building to be above incubating, and so on so that I have eight vertically aligned graphs).

Data sample from matrix C (does not include all columns):

```
        Singing Building Incubating Nestlings Empty Nest
  [1,]       8        8          8         8         13
  [2,]       8        8          8        11          4
  [3,]       9        8          8        12         13
  [4,]       5        4          8        11         13
  [5,]       9        8          8         8         13
  [6,]       9        8          8         8         13
  [7,]       5        8          8        11         13
  [8,]       9        8         10        11         12
  [9,]       9        4          8        10          8
 [10,]       5        7         12        10          8
```

Comment: You might be interested in the [ggridges](https://wilkelab.org/ggridges/) package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This seems neat, but I'm having trouble getting the original figures (G) to work with ggridges. Do I need to reformat my matrix, or is there a way to adjust my second line, e.g. `G<-G+geom_density_ridges(...)`?

Comment: I have no clue what kind of structure `mcmc_dens()` creates and I don't have a way to recreate your `G` object so that I can inspect it myself and figure out how to best answer your question. If you can show how we can make an object shaped like `C` (doesn't need to be the real data) that we can use to trace the steps, we'd be in a better position to help you.

Comment: I'm guessing that if `G` is a ggplot structure, you can get the underlying data from `layer_data(G)` and build a ggplot object de novo that you can then supply with `+ geom_density_ridges(...)`, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! `mcmc_dens` has the argument `facet_args` which turns each figure into its own facet (took me so long because I was unfamiliar with facets). Modifying the first line of my original code gave me the figure I was looking for:

```r
pars <- c("Singing", "Building", "Incubating", "Nestlings", 
          "Empty", "Fledglings", "Interactions", "Foraging")
G <- mcmc_dens(C, pars=pars, facet_args=list(ncol=1, strip.position="left"))
```

This is what the images look like now:

[image: Behaviors]